# Flickering on hover over div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a background color with some opacity on hover over a div. But i get flickering effect over the color once i hover over it. while as the element i hover over  is working properly.
My code and css is as below:

```
    <div class="flip-menu">
            <section class="flip-item-wrap">
                <img class="fake-image" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/11" alt=""><!-- this image will add height to parent element -->
                <input type="checkbox" class="flipper" id="a">
                <label for="a" class="flip-item">
                    <figure class="front"><img class="img_hover" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/1" alt=""></img>

                    </figure>
                    <figure class="back">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/500/500/food/1" alt=""></img>
                        <div class="flip-item-desc">
                            <h4 class="flip-item-title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
                            <p>Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum posuere turpis lacus.</p>
                        </div>
                    </figure>
                </label>
                  <div  style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
                                color: #000000;
                                left: 1px;
                                opacity: 0.8;
                                padding: 4px;
                                 position: absolute;
                                text-transform: uppercase;
                                top: 162px;
                                width: 182px;
                                z-index: 9999;
                                left: 0px;
                                overflow:hidden;" class="hover_div"> 
                     hhh
                  </div>
            </section>
</div>

        .img_hover:hover{
     border:1px solid #888888!important;
    }
     .hover_div{
    display:none;

    }

     .flip-item-wrap :hover + div{
     display: block;
     cursor:pointer;

    }
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle for your code. It'll be easier to solve your problem.

Comment: Be more precise, what do you mean with the flickering effect?

Comment: Change `border:1px solid #888888 !important;` to `outline:1px solid #888888 !important;` in your `.img_hover:hover{` css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. The confusion here arose because in testing your code there is an obvious flicker on the image's border, and that's what Yasser was trying to fix - which he did. But I think you are referring to something else. I suggest starting from scratch and cleaning your code up, that will make things easier - this alone will probably solve your problem. I made a fiddle that accomplishes what I believe you are after.

This should get you started in the right direction.

```
<style>
    .main {
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
    }
    .cover {
        position:absolute;
        background:#ccc;
        opacity:.5;
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        display:none;

    }
    .main:hover .cover {
        display:block;
    }
</style>

<div class="main">
    <div class="cover">&nbsp;</div>
    <img class="img_hover" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/1" alt="">
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p79K4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the flickering to be the border which comes up and shakes the layout a bit. Add this line of css and let me know if this works for you.

```
.img_hover{
     border:1px solid #fff !important;
 }
```

Atlernatively you should add a jsfiddle so that we could help you better.

Edit:

A better way to do this would be this - Thanks [Ruddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2259322/ruddy)

```
.img_hover:hover {
    outline:1px solid #888888!important;
}
```

Comment: Should explain what your doing here.... (Setting a border that is the same as the background color so when the hover occurs there is no movement of the `1px` border being added). Also another way you can do this is changing `border` to `outline`.

Comment: I have added that border on hover but still it's showing the same.

Comment: @Ruddy completely agree with you.

Comment: @user2053590 With `outline` being used [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/nk5RT/) and with this answer being used [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/nk5RT/1/)

Comment: @user2053590 added border on hover ? That you already have. Add one on the img class when not on hover too.

Comment: i have done all that , but still the flickering is there

Comment: Im pretty sure this isnt what the OP means now. @user2053590 explain what you want done and where the problem is.

Comment: All the problem is that i get flickering on hover over image. i want to set some background with some opacity on hover over the image.

Comment: +1 because although I don't think you solved the OP's issue, you saw probably the same thing I saw initially and solved it - the border issue. I think this question was not very clear.